# Object not passing from parent component to child onClick of submit button

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Hi I am trying to pass entire form Data in the form of object from parent component to child component .But it is coming as undefined .I am trying to set
my form data object in FirstName variable in my child component .

Please help... what I am doing wrong

Below is my parent Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {SecondFormComponent} from './secondform.component';
@Component({
selector:'practice-form',
templateUrl:'app/firstform.component.html',

styles : [`h1{color:red;}
         .myClass{
            position:relative;left:546px ;
         }
          `],

})

export class FirstFormComponent{ 

    public applyClass = true ;
    public name ;
    public id ;
    public street ;
    public pcode ;    
    public city ;    
    public gender ;    

    public fname = "karan saxena" ;
    public val ;
    public genders = [
    { value: 'F', display: 'Female' },
    { value: 'M', display: 'Male' }
     ]; 
    onsubmit(value){


        this.gender =value.gender ;
        this.id = value.id;
        this.name = value.sname;
        this.city = value.city;
        this.pcode = value.pcode; 
        this.street = value.street;


        console.log(this.id);
        console.log(this.name);
        console.log(this.city);
        console.log(this.pcode);
        console.log(this.street);
        this.val = value ;       
        console.log(this.val);

    }
}
```

Next below is my template for first component

```
<div class="container">
<div [class.myClass]="applyClass" >
<h1>First Form</h1>
</div>
<form #userFrom="ngForm" novalidate (submit)="onsubmit(userFrom.value)">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Student id</label>
<input type= "text" #_idRef class="form-control" name="id" ngModel>   
<span>{{_idRef.className}}</span> 
</div>    

<div class="form-group">
<label>Student Name</label>
<input type= "text" class="form-control" name="sname" ngModel>    
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label>Street</label>
<input type= "text" class="form-control" name="street" ngModel>    
</div>


<div class="form-group">
<label>City</label>
<input type= "text" class="form-control" name="city" ngModel>    
</div>


<div class="form-group">
<label>Postal Code</label>
<input type= "text" class="form-control" name="pcode" ngModel>    
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Gender</label>
    <div *ngFor="let gender of genders">
        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender"  [value]="gender.value" ngModel>
        {{gender.display}}
        </label>
    </div> 
 </div>

<button class="btn btn-primary">SUBMIT</button>
</form>    
</div>    


<div class="container">
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<th>id</th>
<th>name</th>    
<th>city</th>
<th>pcode</th>
<th>gender</th>
</thead>    

<tbody class="table-hover">
<tr  class="table-striped">  
<td>{{id}}</td>  
<td>{{name}}</td> 
<td>{{city}}</td> 
<td>{{pcode}}</td> 
<td>{{gender}}</td> 
</tr>      
</tbody>    

</table>
</div>

<table-form [FirstName] = 'val'></table-form> // here I am passing form object  to child
```

Below is my child component

```
import { Component , Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector:'table-form',
templateUrl:'app/secondtform.component.html'
})

export class SecondFormComponent{
@Input() FirstName : object ;

}
```

below is my template for child :-

```
<div>
<h1>{{FirstName.sname}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Have your tried this `table-form [(FirstName)] = 'val'></table-form>` //added ()

Comment: any error in console? .. what if you put elvis operator? .. like <h1>{{FirstName?.sname}}</h1> and declare your @Input() FirstName :  any and not like object

Comment: Tried your solution but still didnt work ,,also error on console is :-EXCEPTION: Error in app/secondtform.component.html:2:4 caused by: Cannot read property 'sname' of undefined

Comment: @user3668556 if you have used the safe navigation operator like federico suggested, you should not get that error you are getting... so did you really try `{{FirstName?.sname}}`

Comment: thanks mate ,,,,,,I tried this and now its working {{FirstName?.sname}} , earliar I did only this --> table-form [(FirstName)] = 'val'></table-form> and not {{FirstName?.sname}}

Comment: But my question is why angular needs {{FirstName?.sname}} this in case of an object and not in case of a variable .I have read Nehal's answer below and he says -->  to ensure Angular tries to render it only when sname is available but why ,even if sname is not available angular can display null/undefined but in my case it was not displaying even when sname was there in Firstname

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your problem and here are few things I had to do to get the form and object passing to work:

1. There was no `pname` initialized, you have `fname`, so I changed that to `sname`.
2. I binded all the input fields to their associating variable with `ngModel`.
3. I added a `?` in `{{FirstName.sname}}` to ensure Angular tries to render it only when `sname` is available.
4. Added a `(click)` event binding to update the `gender` value.

Please see the [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/4dWdQ1yysolJoyDak26v?p=preview) for more details.